# APNS feedback service

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

In my application,my providers are using the feedback service to get the list of failed device tokens.But in one scenerio,that one not useful for me .So please check that scenario and tell me how it will be useful.

1)Uninstall the app from device,try to send the notification,But it's failed and added to failed list.

2)call the feedback service and get the failed list and that device token is available on that list.

3)Before send the notification and after got the failed list,i install the app on device.And try to send the notification.

4)That device not get the notification.Because we are not sending the notification to that failed device tokens.

And one more scenario,

after device token added to failed list,i send the notification to remaining tokens and no failures.And i am not going to install the application on device.But next time, feedback service returns zero device tokens(because last time no failures) means no failed device tokens.But i didn't install the app on my device.So now if i send the notification to all device tokens(Including my device token also because it available on my db),notification will failed to send to my device because my device not at install the app.

So how to achieve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app is installed again (3), it will send the device token to your server. When that happens, the device token should be saved in your DB, and from that point forward you'll resume sending push notifications to that device token.

As to the second scenario, when you get a list of failed tokens from the feedback service, you should either delete those tokens from your DB or mark them with some state that would prevent you from sending push notifications to them. It doesn't matter that the next call to the feedback service doesn't return device tokens that were previously returned.